# Meteor Blaze Data Context becomes undefined

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a blaze template like this:

```
{{>jobsheetsTable companyId=companyId}}
```

In the JS for the template I have the onCreated function like this ...

```
Template.jobsheetsTable.onCreated(function(){
  const instance = this;
  instance.companyId = new ReactiveVar();
  console.log(instance, instance.data, instance.data.companyId);
  if(instance.data.companyId){
    instance.companyId.set(instance.data.companyId);
  }
}
```

The issue is that in the console.log statement I notice something odd ...

`instance` is correctly outputting the instance with the `data` object and a `companyId`
`instance.data` however returns `{companyId: undefined}`.

I am not changing `instance.data` anywhere and the function being passed into this template does not change the `companyId`.

Update: Using meteor 1.6.1.

Comment: How do you setup `companyId` value in your parent template instance?

Comment: It's essentially `Meteor.user().roles.company`. When calling that in the console. it returns the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

The `onCreated` callback is only run once per template creation, so the data you get is the one that is provided to the initial creation (likely with you attribute set to `undefined`).

It is likely that the data context is changed after the initial rendering, and this does not trigger the function. as the template is not re-created.

If you are certain that you want to track the data context in the `onCreated` callback, you need to set a reactive dependency on it, using the [`Template.currentData()`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-currentData) reactive data source. Since it needs to be inside a reactive context in order to be re-run when the data changes, you will need to create one, and a convenient method of doing so is via `this.autorun()`, which stops the computation for you when the template is destroyed.

```
Template.jobsheetsTable.onCreated(function(){
  this.companyId = new ReactiveVar();
  this.autorun(() => { // creates a reactive computation
    const data = Template.currentData(); // creates a reactive dependency
    console.log('data context', data);
    if(data.companyId){
      this.companyId.set(data.companyId);
    }
  })
});
```

The code above contains an `autorun` block that will re-run whenever the data context changes.